# Backbone.js sync: A "url" property or function must be specified

Tags: backbone.js, backbone.js-collections

There are a lot of questions about the same error, but this one is different, and weird.

Here's the code that's generating the error:

```
console.log(this.sources.url);
this.sources.sync({
    success: function (collection, response, options) {
        App.debug('Synchronized media sources.');
    },
    error: function (collection, response, options) {
        App.debug('Unable to synchronize media sources.')
        App.debug(response);
    }
});
```

this.sources is a Collection.  The output is:

```
/api/sources
routes.js:40 Uncaught Error: A "url" property or function must be specified
```

So a url is specified.  Any ideas?

Comment: Still not sure why this was happening, but I found a workaround.  I was using sync instead of fetch because I wanted to listen for the sync event.  Then I realized that fetch also triggers a sync event, and switching to fetch fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sync expects a method ( 'create', 'read', 'update'...) By omiting a method you may have confused the arguments.

```
sync: function() {
      return Backbone.sync.apply(this, arguments);
    },


  Backbone.sync = function(method, model, options) {
...
```

It wants something like

```
this.sources.sync('create',{
    success: function (collection, response, options) {
        App.debug('Synchronized media sources.');
    },
    error: function (collection, response, options) {
        App.debug('Unable to synchronize media sources.')
        App.debug(response);
    }
});
```

Comment: This is not true. You cannot save a `Collection` this way; it is not RESTful. But you can always save a model, like this: `var collectionWrapperModel = new (Backbone.Model.extend( {url: 'api/endpoint'} ))( {update: this.collection.models} ); collectionWrapperModel.save();` Note that the server would then receive a POST or PUT message with a property called `update`, which would then need to be processed appropriately. I'm not posting this as the answer since the questioner was actually trying to `fetch` his Collection.